# Get free-spinning bolt out of TV?

Tags: mounting, hardware, home-theater

I am trying to remove an HDTV wall mount from the TV, but: a handyman tightened one of the bolts overzealously, and now it's stuck.  Specifically: The bolt turns freely, but does not reverse out of the TV.  I assume the metal sleeve in the TV broke off, inside, and now my screwdriver is turning the bolt and the sleeve around it.

How can I get this thing out of the TV, and thus free it from the wall mount?

Comment: Pulling on the bolt as you try to loosen it might help.  The pressure could cause the threaded bit inside the TV to hold still, allowing you to free the bolt.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a tiny bit of space between the bracket and the tv?  If so I'd use a hacksaw to cut through the screw and remove the bracket.  If space is really tight, try removing the blade and using it with your hands.

After that, you'll have to see what you are working with.  If you are lucky, maybe you can get some epoxy or glue around the bolt inside of the TV to freeze it and then use locking pliers to remove the rest of the screw or drill it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'd either try to drill out the head of the bolt (hopefully, it's a cheapie and not hardened) or set a hacksaw in the gap and spin the bolt with a drill.

Both approaches create metal shavings that you really don't want inside the TV, so tape off any ventilation holes and have someone standing beside you with a vacuum cleaner. Be sure to have the person with the vacuum grounded, as vacs can generate static electricity that could zap your TV.

Maybe taking it somewhere is sounding pretty good at this point...